# How to get a raw transaction in txpool via JSON RPC?

Tags: raw-transaction, txpool

Is there any way to get a raw transaction via JSON RPC? I know how to get tx_hash from txpool, next I can get data like "from", "to", "gas", "input"... But how to get raw hex string?

I mean a raw tx like this:

```
0xf8ab82127c8506fc23ac0082926994b2a736980815d9c3a960e1c2a88042e4a9c9397880b844a9059cbb00000000000000000000000098aa1ad237106608b44e3a2fad6755fd5d486d3800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004a484410025a024bd7fe9b26f465ea5a06c5feb90894c60e7a5eb06a8d4bed6a729789be41660a02a9c4c909a3ab60ae76983706f1b72044572d5b9a28445771365d95ad03d1723
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there's no geth api to obtain the raw transaction. However you can get all tx fields with `eth_getTransactionByHash` and construct the raw transaction with them.

Comment: How can I construct raw_tx with fields from eth_getTransactionByHash?
As I understand, I need to have private_key to do it. Is it possible to create raw_tx without private key?

Comment: @MaxBlock You can use [ethereumjs-tx](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm/tree/master/packages/tx) and construct a transaction passing the fields returned by getTransactionByHash (including the signature v, r, s). Then use `.serialize()` to obtain the raw transaction.